# Event to update product price before order place

Tags: magento-1.9

This is the second time, I am adding this question.

What event I should trigger that will update product price just before placing the order, so that admin would see the updated product price in the order.

I tried "sales_order_place_before", but its not working.

Here's my observer code:

```
class CustomPriceUpdate_Checkout_Model_Observer{
  public function update_price($observer){
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
   foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
       $product = $item->getProduct();//if you need it
       $additional = 23;
       $finalPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() + $additional;
       $item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice);
       $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
       $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
       $item->save();
     //your magic here.
    }
    $quote->save();  
    Mage::log("Order is placed");
  }
}
```

I am seeing the system.log showing "Order is placed", but product price still showing the older price in order.

Please suggest.

Answer (score -2):

Try this its work for me

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Always_Nallavan>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Always_Nallavan>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <alwaysnallavan>
                <class>Nallavan_Model</class>
            </alwaysnallavan>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <always_nallavan_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Always_Nallavan_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>orderBefore</method>
                    </always_nallavan_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
class Always_Nallavan_Model_Observer
{

    public function orderBefore($observer)
    {
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::log($data->debug(), null, "order.log", true);
    }
}
```